# Testing SOAP web services

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'd like to test a SOAP service. I'm using nUnit to test it, nevertheless I've no idea about how to mock them (using NSubstitute for example...).

Is there some stuff helping code over there?

How could I create integration tests?

I'm using C# .net projects...

**EDIT**

I''ve create a service which exposes an interface:

```
<services>
  <service name="Core.Kernel">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Core.Communication.ICoreService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Core/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

where, `Core.Communication.ICoreService` is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICoreService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Core.Communication.Entities.Plugin> GetPlugins(Communication.Entities.UserIdentity userIdentity);
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Communication.Entities.ChannelPlugin> GetPluginChannels(Communication.Entities.UserIdentity userIdentity);
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Communication.Entities.ChannelPlugin> GetPluginChannelsById(Communication.Entities.UserIdentity userIdentity, string pluginId);

    #region ICoreConfiguration interface

    [OperationContract]
    void AddUserIdentity(Communication.Entities.UserIdentity userIdentity);

    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveUserIdentity(Communication.Entities.UserIdentity userIdentity);

    #endregion

}
```

I've create an project which uses this service and I've set this as a service reference.

```
public partial class UIController : UIFrame.Core.Controllable
{

    public IEnumerable<UIContainer.Entities.Core.Plugin> getPlugins()
    {
        this.service.GetPlugins()...;
    }

    public IEnumerable<UIContainer.Entities.Core.ChannelPlugin> getPluginChannels()
    {
        this.service.getPluginChannels()...;
    }

    public IEnumerable<UIContainer.Entities.Core.ChannelPlugin> getPluginChannelsById(string pluginId)
    {
        this.service.GetPluginChannelsById(...);
    }

    public void AddUserIdentity()
    {
        this.service.AddUserIdentity(this.coreUserIdentity);
    }

    public void RemoveUserIdentity()
    {
        this.service.RemoveUserIdentity(this.coreUserIdentity);
    }

}
```

As you can see I'm creating a slight wrapper of straightforward proxy of `service`.

I'd like to add integration testing in order to check connectivity, interface compatibility, and so on...

Comment: If you are asking about help with mocking something, then it would be nice to see what you are trying to test/mock. Otherwise answer is http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/

Comment: I've edited the post.